# My Compute Prefix Function implementation in python gives false result

Tags: python, algorithm, knuth-morris-pratt

I implemented the Compute-Prefix-Function in Python, but it gives me false result (I am beginner in python)
Can somebody help me what is wrong in my implementation compare with the pseudo code?

```
def pi_prefix_fuggveny(pattern):
    P = list(pattern)
    m = len(P)
    a = [0] * m
    k = 0

    for q in range(2, m):
        while k > 0 and P[k+1] != P[q]:
            k = a[k]
        if P[k+1] == P[q]:
            k = k + 1
        a[q] = k

    return a

print pi_prefix_fuggveny("ababaca")
```

The result is: `[0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0]`.
But the correct result must be: `[0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1]`

The [pseudoc code is available here](http://cs.indstate.edu/~kmandumula/presentation.pdf). It is on the 7th page

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue is that the paper you linked is using 1-indexed arrays, whereas we typically use 0-indexed arrays in the coding world. I adjusted the indexes accordingly:

```
def pi_prefix_fuggveny(pattern):
    P = list(pattern)
    m = len(pattern)
    a = [0] * m
    k = 0

    for q in range(2, m + 1):
        while k > 0 and P[k] != P[q - 1]:
            k = a[k - 1]
        if P[k] == P[q - 1]:
            k += 1
        a[q - 1] = k

    return a


print(pi_prefix_fuggveny("ababaca"))
```

I also think that the paper makes a mistake and the output should be:

```
[0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1]
```

(as this program produces), not

```
[0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1]
```

Comment: That's because the algorithm is wrong. The `while` loop should be an `if` loop.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem just an `if`, no loop :)